# Зачем используют min-height?

Tags: html, css

Много верстальщиков делают высоту секций с помощью min-height, но зачем? Разве высоту секций не задает контент в ней?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что иногда нужно (по дизайнерской задумке, например) что бы секция была больше чем в ней есть контента.

Comment: Можно же все делать с помощью паддингов

Comment: @vvanyazz: если контент динамический, то такое не прокатит.

Comment: @vvanyazz нельзя) вот допустим у тебя есть блок в котором контента на 2 строки, а в соседнем блоке на 1 строку, но они должны при этом иметь одинаковую высоту, при задании паддинга, ты изменишь высоту обеих блоков и она будет разной